# Fire PUT request using CURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl, tomcat7

I am firing PUT request from PHP CURL following are my CURL config details , the motive of PUT 
request is to send XML request to the server , the server is TOMCAT 7

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $xmlreq);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, 2000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-type: application/xml', 'Content-length:2000') 
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.5) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/1.0');
$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo $data;
```

But i am not getting anything in return

after monitoring i noticed that i am getting following error , but dont know how to resolve it

```
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error parsing media type 'application/xml;charset: utf-8'
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.HttpHelper.clientError(HttpHelper.java:262)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.HttpHelper.getContentType(HttpHelper.java:88)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.HttpHelper.getContentType(HttpHelper.java:74)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getMediaType(ContainerRequest.java:544)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.filterFormParameters(WebComponent.java:769)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:376)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:451)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:632)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error parsing media type 'application/xml;charset: utf-8'
    com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider.fromString(MediaTypeProvider.java:77)
    com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider.fromString(MediaTypeProvider.java:50)
    javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:119)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.HttpHelper.getContentType(HttpHelper.java:86)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.HttpHelper.getContentType(HttpHelper.java:74)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getMediaType(ContainerRequest.java:544)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.filterFormParameters(WebComponent.java:769)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:376)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:451)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:632)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

root cause

java.text.ParseException: Expected separator '=' instead of ':'
    com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader.nextSeparator(HttpHeaderReader.java:112)
    com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader.readParameters(HttpHeaderReader.java:244)
    com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider.valueOf(MediaTypeProvider.java:95)
    com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider.fromString(MediaTypeProvider.java:75)
    com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider.fromString(MediaTypeProvider.java:50)
    javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:119)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.HttpHelper.getContentType(HttpHelper.java:86)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.HttpHelper.getContentType(HttpHelper.java:74)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getMediaType(ContainerRequest.java:544)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.filterFormParameters(WebComponent.java:769)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:376)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:451)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:632)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the server does not support custom requests. You should be able to do it with a POST though. Have you tried sniffing to check what messages a client can receives and sends ?

Comment: How can i sniff or monitor the request and response ?

Comment: Using a sniffer like wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

Set this line

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
```

to this line

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```

So you will get the response header, too. There you'll get more information about the "error"